# How to create a rails service for controllers with access to cookies and session

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create a service to DRY my controllers, and make them more readable (and avoid the use of **concerns**), but this is not a common service, because it'll be able to get and set cookies and session entries. How can I achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a services something like:

```
class FooService

  delegate *%w(
    session
    cookies
  ), to: :controller

  class << self 

    def call(args={})
      new(args).call
    end

  end # Class Methods

  #=====================================================================
  # Instance Methods      
  #=====================================================================

  def initialize(args)
    args.each do |k,v|
      class_eval do 
        attr_accessor k
      end
      send("#{k}=",v)
    end        
  end

  def call

  end

end
```

And then, from within your controller, call it something like:

```
FooService.call controller: self, other: :args
```

When called this way, you'll have the methods `controller` and `other` in the instance of `FooService` that hold the values of `controller` (the one that called the service) and `:args`, respectively. You'll also have the methods `session` and `cookies` that are the session and cookies held by the `controller`. Then, you can do with them as you like.

Comment: This is causing `private method 'cookies' called for [controller]` for me ..